# Generate a list with only the 2 first values of each entry in another list

Tags: python, list

How should I generate a list(dayList) from the values of a list I already have(startTid). I want to only use the 2 first values of every entry. I'm able to **print** out what I want with the code below.

```
    
def getDays(filnavn):   #gi en liste med datoer for måneden
    startTid, stopTid, forbruk  = getAMSdata(filnavn)

    for i in range(len(startTid)):
        entry = startTid[i][0:2]
        print(entry)
    
    #return dayList

    getDays(FIL)
```

Comment: You know how to print them but not how to add them to a list?

Comment: Please give your sample inputs/outputs to make it easier to follow.

Comment: I have an assignment where I imported data from a .csv file and made a list without figuring the details of what I did, but now I do! (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accumulate the entries into a list:

```py
dayList = []
for i in range(len(startTid)):
    dayList.append(startTid[i][0:2])
return dayList
```

But using a list comprehension would be more idiomatic:

```py
return [s[0:2] for s in startTid]
```

Comment: Is the `t` supposed to be in there? after the append?

Comment: Thanks! This clarified some details I didn't get about making and populating lists! (y)

Comment: In my function `getAMSdata(filnavn)` i have returned the the lists `return startTid, stopTid, forbruk`. I can fetch `startTid` as `a = getAMSdata(filnavn)[0]` or as done above. Can i fetch my list `startTid` in any other way where i just use `startTid`?

Comment: Guess the best option is to define just define `startTid = getAMSdata(filnavn)[0]`and then use it when needed.